# cpcb site scraper giving unauthorized access in output

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, captcha

https://github.com/thejeshgn/cpcbccr, i was trying to use this get pollutant data from cpcb site, i was able to run setup_pull.py without any error but when i try to run pull.py it runs but give unauthorized access in output database table. i try using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import base64
import hashlib
import dataset
import json
import time
import re

db = dataset.connect("sqlite:////mnt/c/Users/shekhar/OneDrive/Desktop/New folder/cpcb_auto/cpcbccr/data/db/data.db")
table = db["request_status_data"]
status_code = 1
row_exists = table.find_one(status_code=status_code)

while row_exists:
    print(
        "#####################################################"
        + str(datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    )
    db.begin()
    query_name = row_exists["query_name"]
    print("query_name = " + str(query_name))
    encoded_data = row_exists["encoded_data"]

    headers = {
        "Origin": "https://app.cpcbccr.com",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Referer": "https://app.cpcbccr.com/ccr",
        #"Authorization": ,
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Host": "app.cpcbccr.com",
    }
    
   
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.get("https://app.cpcbccr.com/ccr/#/caaqm-dashboard-all/caaqm-landing")

    input("Press Enter to continue after solving the CAPTCHA manually...")

   
    driver.quit()
    
    try:
        r = requests.post(
            "https://app.cpcbccr.com/caaqms/fetch_table_data",
            headers=headers,
            data=encoded_data,
            verify=False,  # Enable SSL certificate verification (recommended)
        )

        # Check the HTTP status code and handle the response
        if r.status_code == 200:
            print("Awesome response code 200")
            json_data = json.dumps(r.json())
            json_data_hash = hashlib.md5(json_data.encode("UTF8"))
            row_exists["json_data"] = json_data
            row_exists["json_data_hash"] = json_data_hash.hexdigest()
            row_exists["status_code"] = r.status_code
            # Handle the JSON data as needed
        else:
            print("HTTP error:", r.status_code)
            row_exists["json_data"] = ""
            row_exists["status_code"] = r.status_code
            # Handle the error response as needed

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Request error:", e)
        # Handle network or request-related errors

    # Perform any necessary updates to the database or other actions here
    print("UPDATING")
    table.update(row_exists, ["id"])
    db.commit()
    
    row_exists = table.find_one(status_code=status_code)
    if row_exists:
        pass
    else:
        break

print("_______________________________________________________________")
```

without any luck. can somebody please help me. Any tips are well appreciated

i tried using selenium to solve the issue but no luck as i am not a programmer. i want to automatically download data from the https://app.cpcbccr.com/ccr continuous monitoring station. any kind of help, tips please.

Comment: I tried adding cookies to header but no success it still gives me unauthorized request in output.